# remove virtual directory in IIS Express created in error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I clicked on create virtual directory of the web tab of the properties menu.
My application now isn't running (the published version is)
It just hangs when any of my controllers code is executed
I think I've messed up the IIS config
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 34):

[image]

My file was located here:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

Entries will look like this

```
<application path="/virtualDirectoryName" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\projects\Project1" />
                </application>
```

Comment: I did this, but it keep creating the site every time i run the project.

Comment: Check the project settings, make sure the deploy setting doesn't specify the virtual path.

Comment: If using Visual Studio 2017 the configuration file might be _hidden_ in a  `.vs` folder that's not visible.

Comment: I deleted the applicationhost.config file, restarted Visual Studio and it worked.

Comment: I got rid of .vs folder and restart Visual Studio. Problem solved.

Answer (score 27):

None of this worked for me - possibly because I'm working with a later version of the tools (VS 2017). I finally found the correct appplicationhost.config file in the .vs directory for the solution, edited it, rebooted, and it worked.

Comment: Thanks! Removing competing bindings from different projects in VS 2017 (.vs directory) and rebooting fixed this for me

Comment: Works in VS 2019 as well.

Comment: Reboot was a must for me even though it doesn't make sense (why it's needed).

Answer (score 14):

If you created another virtual directory by mistake, go to your .vs folder inside your solution/project folder and look for a file called:

```
applicationhost.config
```

and change/fix what is inside the tag:

```
<sites>
   <site name="YourSite" id="1">
      ...
   </site>
   ...
</sites>
```

Hope this helps! :D

Answer (score 8):

I realize this has been answered a few times over, but had this exact same issue in `VS 2019` so I performed the following steps:

- Closed the `Solution`
- Navigated in the file system to the `.vs` folder within my solution and deleted it
- Reopened `Solution` and rebuilt.

Upon reopening the solution and `Starting` the project, it appeared to have worked without any sort of reboot.

*Some may consider deleting the `.vs` folder destructive in some way but given the fact it's normally excluded from most (if not all source control systems) there isn't really anything mission critical in there and it all gets rebuilt anyways.*

Comment: This just saved me after about an hour of frustration when IIS Express just suddenly decided to start serving old versions of my app during debugging, thanks!

Comment: this helped a little but in the end i just cloned a fresh repo. All of the meta files that were corrupted just recreated fresh this way

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue today. The simplest way to deal with this is just simply change the Port number. Go to the Properties of the Project which you have made as Startup Project.
Then...

Click to view => [Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8CIw.png)

Let's say the initial port number is 62168. Just increment it by 1.

Click to view => [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpDjL.png)

And create a new virtual directory. Now execute the project again. This time it'll work.

Steps:

> Go to Properties window of the project selected as the StartUp Project
>
> Select the "Web" section present in the LHS of the Properties window
>
> Go to the Servers part (which is present below the "Start Action" part )
>
> In the Project URL section, increment the value of Port Number by 1 or 2 (modified Port number must be free) and click 
>     on "Create Virtual Directory"
>
> Save the changes and run the application using CTRL+F5

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you please add text descriptions of where to make these changes, as well as the images?

Comment: Sure... I'll add the steps in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use appcmd.exe in C:\program files (x86)\IISExpress

`appcmd list vdir` should list the virtual directories and 
`appcmd delete vdir VDIR.NAME` to delete. Or, if you use Powershell, the commands start with `.\`, e.g., `.\appcmd list vdir`.

Answer (score 2):

**VS 2019 -**

There are multiple places that the `applicationhost.config` resides. Two of those are where the virtual directory data is put.

First location:

`C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`

Second location:

`C:\YourPathToSolutionFolder\.vs\SolutionName\config\applicationhost.config.`

** please note: in the .vs there are two folders one is the config folder and the other should be the name of your solution. Navigate into your solution named folder and you will find another config folder. Inside there is the `applicationhost.config` file you need to edit.

In both files you will need to remove the following (I just search for virtualdirectory).

```
<application path="/virtualDirectoryName" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\projects\Project1" />
</application>
```

Hopefully you won't have to delete the entire .vs folder which is an option if needed.

**Note:** This combines two answer from above [Diego Murakami](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375607/892792) and [BraveNewMath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29289060/892792)

Comment: The second location was `C:\YourPathToSolutionFolder\.vs\SolutionName\config\applicationhost.config` for me. @ZombieCode, can you check if you missed the `config` part of the path?

Comment: You are correct. Thank you for catching that. I have fixed the post.